# Why does my button only work once in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a window that's background changes color when you press a button. But the button only changes the color once, then doesn't do anything.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

colors = ["blue", "red", "green"]

colorChoice = random.choice(colors)

window = Tk()

window.geometry("400x400")

def changeColor():
    window.configure(background=str(colorChoice))

button = Button(window, text = "click me!", command=changeColor)
button.pack(side = TOP)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't choose a new random color each time `changeColor()` is called, you keep using the value of `colorChoice` that was assigned when the script started.

Comment: Put the assignment inside the function. Also, `colorChoice` is already a string, you don't need to call `str()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `colorChoice` inside of function like this:

```
def changeColor():
   colorChoice = random.choice(colors)
   window.configure(background=colorChoice)
```